# rewrite-tag filter in fluent-bit 1.6.0 hangs on

Tags: filter, fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

I tried the `rewrite-tag` example written in the [documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/rewrite-tag) with **fluent-bit 1.6.0**

I was able to get rid of the following warning with the fix mentioned in the [Git](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/commit/94bdace9f2d9dd473c01f75b7201758911664c10)

```
[2020/10/19 15:17:31] [ warn] [input chunk] no matching route for input chunk 16817-1603100851.153798000.flb
```

But now I get nothing on the output. It’s hanging on after following line

```
...
[2020/10/19 15:42:00] [ info] [engine] started (pid=28286)
[2020/10/19 15:42:00] [ info] [storage] version=1.0.6, initializing...
[2020/10/19 15:42:00] [ info] [storage] in-memory
[2020/10/19 15:42:00] [ info] [storage] normal synchronization mode, checksum disabled, max_chunks_up=128
[2020/10/19 15:42:00] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
```

Any idea why that is?

Following is the content of configuration file (same as in the documentation)

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush     1
    Log_Level info

[INPUT]
    NAME   dummy
    Dummy  {"tool": "fluent", "sub": {"s1": {"s2": "bit"}}}
    Tag    test_tag

[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match         test_tag
    Rule          $tool ^(fluent)$  from.$TAG.new.$tool.$sub['s1']['s2'].out false
    Emitter_Name  re_emitted

[OUTPUT]
    Name   stdout
    Match  from.*
```

I named the configuration file as ***example.conf***

The way I ran it as below

```
fluent-bit -c example.conf
```

Comment: Show us your configurations and a sample log and your expected result.

Comment: I'm using the same example configuration content given in the `rewrite-tag` documentation which I have already linked. In there INPUT uses `dummy` and you can see the output in my question content.

Comment: What if in `stdout` output you use `*` in `Match` section? Are there any outputs? What are the tags?

Comment: Same result with no extra output. Hanging on the same location.

Comment: Seems we are having opened issue in [Github](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2579). I wonder whether this is only related to macOS

Answer (score 0):

There is a known regression, please upgrade to v1.6.1:

```
$ ../../build/bin/fluent-bit -c conf 
Fluent Bit v1.6.1
* Copyright (C) 2019-2020 The Fluent Bit Authors
* Copyright (C) 2015-2018 Treasure Data
* Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
* https://fluentbit.io

[2020/10/19 12:25:49] [ info] [engine] started (pid=1830124)
[2020/10/19 12:25:49] [ info] [storage] version=1.0.6, initializing...
[2020/10/19 12:25:49] [ info] [storage] in-memory
[2020/10/19 12:25:49] [ info] [storage] normal synchronization mode, checksum disabled, max_chunks_up=128
[2020/10/19 12:25:49] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
[0] from.test_tag.new.fluent.bit.out: [1603131950.103238001, {"tool"=>"fluent", "sub"=>{"s1"=>{"s2"=>"bit"}}}]
[0] from.test_tag.new.fluent.bit.out: [1603131951.102535915, {"tool"=>"fluent", "sub"=>{"s1"=>{"s2"=>"bit"}}}]
```

Comment: Tried with 1.6.1 version as well. Still the same issue. Isn't this `rewrite-tag` feature not compatible with **macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.7)** ?

Comment: Can confirm this issue is related to macOS. Because I tried with an Ubuntu VM (20.04.1) and this works. @edsiper glad we can get a fix for macOS as well.